# how to have lua call a c++ function that returns multiple values to lua

Tags: c++, lua

my code (partial)
c++:

```
lua_register(L, "GetPosition", lua_GetPosition);

int lua_GetPosition(lua_State* L)
{
    Entity e = static_cast<Entity>(lua_tointeger(L, 1));
    TransformComponent* trans = TransformComponentPool.GetComponentByEntity(e);
    if (trans != nullptr)
    {
        lua_pushnumber(L, trans->transform->position.x);
        lua_pushnumber(L, trans->transform->position.y);
        lua_pushnumber(L, trans->transform->position.z);
    }
    else
    {
        lua_pushnumber(L, 0);
        lua_pushnumber(L,0);
        lua_pushnumber(L, 0);
        LOG_ERROR("Transform not found");
    }
    return 1;
}
```

lua:

```
local x = 69
local y = 69
local z = 69
x,y,z = GetPosition(e)
print("xyz =",x,y,z)
```

I expected "xyz =   1.0     1.0     1.0"
I got "xyz =   1.0     nil     nil"

What's the right way to do this so lua sees all return values?

Comment: You need to return the number of values you have pushed: `return 3`.

Comment: you can simply write `local x, y, z = GetPosition(e)` btw. There is no need to initialize x,y,z with values here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Lua calls your function it will check its return value to find out how many values it should fetch from the stack. In your case that's `1`. How else would Lua know how many of the pushed values you want to return?

From [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual 4.6 Functions and Types](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#4.6):

> In order to communicate properly with Lua, a C function must use the
> following protocol, which defines the way parameters and results are
> passed: a C function receives its arguments from Lua in its stack in
> direct order (the first argument is pushed first). So, when the
> function starts, lua_gettop(L) returns the number of arguments
> received by the function. The first argument (if any) is at index 1
> and its last argument is at index lua_gettop(L). **To return values to
> Lua, a C function just pushes them onto the stack, in direct order
> (the first result is pushed first), and
> returns in C the number of
> results.** Any other value in the stack below the results will be
> properly discarded by Lua. Like a Lua function, a C function called by
> Lua can also return many results.
>
> As an example, the following function receives a variable number of
> numeric arguments and returns their average and their sum:
>
> ```
>  static int foo (lua_State *L) {
>    int n = lua_gettop(L);    /* number of arguments */
>    lua_Number sum = 0.0;
>    int i;
>    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
>      if (!lua_isnumber(L, i)) {
>        lua_pushliteral(L, "incorrect argument");
>        lua_error(L);
>      }
>      sum += lua_tonumber(L, i);
>    }
>    lua_pushnumber(L, sum/n);        /* first result */
>    lua_pushnumber(L, sum);         /* second result */
>    return 2;                   /* number of results */
>  }
> ```